# What is the difference between Web Fragment Project and Dynamic Web Project?

Tags: java, eclipse, web

What is the difference between Web Fragment Project and Dynamic Web Project on Eclipse?
Which one would you recommend to use for building a clean structural website?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IBM [defines Web Fragment](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwebfragproj.html) as follows:

> A web fragment is a logical partitioning of the web application in
>   such a way that the frameworks being used within the web application
>   can define all the artifacts without requiring you to edit or add
>   information in the `web.xml`.

Furthermore:

> A web fragment is a mechanism for either defining or extending the
>   deployment descriptor of a web application by means of pluggable
>   library jars that contain both the incremental deployment information
>   (in the `web-fragment.xml`) and potentially any related or relevant
>   classes. The web fragment is also packaged as a library (jar), with
>   the `web-fragment.xml` in the `META-INF` directory. Consequently, the
>   web fragment project is essentially a Utility project, with the
>   addition of a web fragment facet to it. The web fragment facet enables
>   you to add relevant context-sensitive functionality to the fragment
>   project.

Essentially, Web Fragments (introduced in Servlet 3.x) allows you to create a reusable portion (or fragment) of the deployment descriptor, `web.xml`.

So, if you want to create a complete, dynamic web application, create a "Dynamic Web Project" in Eclipse. Essentially, you need `web.xml` for the application server/container to deploy your application and "Dynamic Web Project" helps with this approach.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have already read the IBM document. Sadly, I am not a Web Development wizard and the explanation that they provided was not comprehensive.

Comment: It simply means that you can breakdown your `web.xml` configuration file into fragments. Those fragments can be further created into packages (with relevant jars). Once you're done, you can now create a web application `web.xml` and specify all your web fragments into one `web.xml`. A web application **requires** an deployment descriptor file `web.xml` that the application server/container can use for deployment.